# Rxjs: depending on observable value, pipe with mergeMap or switchMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

We have a request service which executes http requests.
All requests implement the IRequest interface, which contains the http-method and an execute function, which in its turn returns another observable.

The RequestService has an overload which accepts a source observable and a requestfactory that returns an IRequest instance based on the source observable's value.

```
export interface IRequest<TResponse> {
    __method: string;
    execute(): Observable<TResponse>;
}

class RequestService<TSource, TResponse> {
    public execute(source: Observable<TSource>, requestFactory: (input: TSource) => IRequest<TResponse>): Observable<TResponse> {
        return source.pipe(
            map(x => requestFactory(x)),
            switchMap(x => x.execute()),
        );
    }
}
```

Ofcourse, a lot more is done in the service (logging, default error handling, ...) but most is irrelevant for the question.

Now, this all works like a charm, but what we would like to do, is to use `switchMap` for GET-requests and 'mergeMap' for POST, PUT, DELETE requests by default.

We cannot seem to get this working. We need access to the IRequest instance after it has been created by the factory, which is only possible if we have the source observable's value. However, when in an operator, we can't control the choice between switchMap or mergeMap anymore.

Our next choice was to create our own `RequestMapOperator` which would create an instance of `MergeMapOperator` or `SwitchMapOperator` and use the appropriate next, complete and error methods. However, the `SwitchMapOperator` is not exported by the rxjs library.

So before creating our own Subscriber class which would be just a combination of the `MergeMapSubscriber` and the `SwitchMapSubscriber`, we would like to know if we're missing something.

---

**TL;DR**

We would like an operator which, depending on the source observable's value, flattens to a new observable with mergeMap or switchMap.

Comment: This is a problem I've been encountering. We've resorted to writing our own `RequestMapOperator` but encountered some problems (switching between different implementations of `_next` and race conditions) If you find a solution please share it! Thank you!

Comment: Still hoping someone will come up with an answer :-) For now, we too have resorted to writing our own `RequestMapOperator` and Subscriber by comparing and combining the source from both the mergeMap and switchMap operators. In our case, we assume that for the same source observable (a request), the choice between switch and merge functionality never changes, because the request's method never changes. If it does, we throw an error (in the `_next` method like you mentioned), which in reality it probably never will.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RXJS iif function which takes condition function as first param and based on value returned decides which observable to subscribe to.

For example.

```
class RequestService<TSource, TResponse> {
    public execute(source: Observable<TSource>, requestFactory: (input: TSource) => IRequest<TResponse>): Observable<TResponse> {
        return source.pipe(
            map(x => requestFactory(x)),
            // using mergemap outside because we don't want to cancel inner 
            // observable
            margeMap((x) => 
              iif(() => x.method === "GET", 
               switchMap(x => x.execute()),
               margeMap(x => x.execute())
              )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried first, but the `iif` operator expects an observable (well, a subscribable to be correct) as the second and third parameters. Both `switchMap` and `mergeMap` are of type `OperatorFunction`. Thanks for the suggestion though.